# Too few transcripts from transcriptome assembler Oases

Tags: bioinformatics, genomics, rna-sequencing

I am trying to run Oases for transcriptome assembly. The result is far from expected, so I would like to ask whether I am running it in a right way? Thanks.

Here is my running command:

```
python scripts/oases_pipeline.py -m 25 -M 29 -o output -d " -strand_specific -shortPaired data/reads.fa" -p " -min_trans_lgth 100 -ins_length 300"
```

My library is strand-specific and pair-ended with length 67bp. The reads are shuffled as:

```
>0(left_mate_forwarded)
ACTC...
>1(right_mate_reverse_complemented)
TATA...
```

I got some transcripts, but are far from the transcripts annotated, also far from the result of Trinity. The longest contig from Oases is ~2500bp (vs. ~10000bp from cufflinks and ~6000bp from Trinity). The N50 value is also low. It only reports 20 contigs those cover full-length of some transcripts from Cufflinks (totally ~4000), while Trinity reports ~650.

The dataset I am using is a subset of *S. pombe*. Does it matter?

Could somebody help me point out whether something wrong here?

Comment: You mentioned that *the result is far from expected*--in what way? Is it just the number of transcripts, or the lengths of those transcripts?

Comment: Also, as stated in the [FAQ](http://biology.stackexchange.com/faq): *Questions on interdisciplinary subjects like bioinformatics are also welcome, as long as they focus on the biological part of the subject*. I'm afraid if you can't highlight a significant biological component to you question, it's likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Em, I tried to post to BioStar, but nobody answers me...

Comment: Here is the mailing list for Oases, http://listserver.ebi.ac.uk/mailman/listinfo/oases-users also there is a thread in SEQanswers http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3877&highlight=oases some people also have problems to get Oases work.

Comment: Unfortunately, if nobody answered on Biostars, the chance of getting an answer *here* is very slim indeed …